ReSharper not applying the 'new' parenthesis space formatting rule in Code Cleanup
It is not a duplicate question. Because my question asks why Resharper stopped making spaces, however, another question is asking how to add spaces. It is two different questions.
I've set a settings to add a space before new parentheses to have a space between new and ():
List<int> list = new ();

The setting in Resharper looks like this:

However, after running Resharper Code clean up space is not occured:

And the result looks like this:

Could you tell please how to add space between new and () after running Code cleanup?

Does this answer your question? How to prevent Resharper of removing whitespace for new ()

@PiersMyers yeah, this is the setting that I've used in my Resharper. However, it does not add any space between new and (). So it looks like this new()

All the examples of "target typed new" I've seen are without a space (new()) - I prefer that way, but each to their own. Are you using the latest version of ReSharper? It might be worth raising an issue with Jetbrains if you think it's a bug.

As far as I see, you excluded the "Reformat code" item in the custom code cleanup profile. Try turning it on or using the "Built-in: Full Cleanup" profile. Does it help?

@MaryPleskunina you are absolutely right! Oooops! It is my fault! I am sorry! If my question hadn't been closed, I would definitely mark your reply as an answer! Thanks a lot!

@PiersMyers It is not a duplicate question. Because my question asks why Resharper stopped making spaces, however, another question is asking how to add spaces. It is two different questions. Actually, MaryPleskunina has shown a reason why it stopped. Could you, please, unlock my question to allow make answer by Mary? It would be really great to have an answer to simplify the future search of other users.

Duplicate retracted - I initially thought it was a formatting issue for new and () with or without spaces between but it was actually due to not including that rule in your Code Cleanup. Also didn't realise the question would be closed after just one (duplicate) close vote - apologies for that.

@MaryPleskunina feel free to make an answer! And I will mark it as an answer! Thank you!

I have amened the question's title to better represent the issue you were having which was nothing to do with the actual formatting but the exclusion of that rule in your Code Cleanup. :)

As far as I see, the "Reformat code" item in the custom code cleanup profile has been excluded. Try turning it on or using the "Built-in: Full Cleanup" profile.
